# What is the best way to run individual t tests on columns of a data frame in R at the same time?

Tags: r

I have a large data frame containing peak intensity readings for about 300 different proteins related to breast cancer from 70 different tissue cores taken from a tissue microarray. The data frame looks like this:

| Core | Behavior | Protein1 | Protein2 | Protein3 | ... | Protein300 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Normal Breast | 1240 | 450 | 545 | ... | 598 |
| 2 | CIS | 350 | 629 | 1496 | ... | 345 |
| 3 | CIS | 3040 | 500 | 345 | ... | 3456 |
| 4 | Normal Breast | 800 | 789 | 2348 | ... | 456 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | 898 |
| 70 | CIS | 589 | 2305 | 723 | ... | 4567 |

I want to run 300 individual t-tests for peak intensity readings for each protein where the Behavior column ('Normal Breast' vs. 'CIS') is the grouping variable and the peak intensity readings under each protein column is the dependent variable. Sample sizes for 'Normal Breast' vs. 'CIS' are not equal. It would also be nice to have a function to group the proteins by whether or not p<0.05 so I do not have to manually comb through each t-test result.

Answer (score 0):

May be this helps

```
nm1 <- grep('Protein', names(df1), value = TRUE)
lapply(nm1, function(nm) 
   t.test(as.formula(paste0(nm, "~ Behavior")), df1[c("Behavior", nm)]))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Core = 1:4, Behavior = c("Normal Breast", "CIS", 
"CIS", "Normal Breast"), Protein1 = c(1240, 350, 3040, 800), 
    Protein2 = c(450, 629, 500, 789)), class = "data.frame", 
    row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```